# Подскажите как сделать такую css тень?

Tags: css

Подскажите как сделать средствами CSS такую тень у блока:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.brown {
  width: 180px; height: 50px;
  background-color: #80423a;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #000, 0 6px 0 0 #000, -3px 0 0 0 #000, -3px 3px 0 0 #000, 3px 0 0 0 #000, 3px 3px 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="brown"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  background: brown;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 11em;
  height: 5.5em;
}
div {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px silver,
   0 -20px 0 -10px black,
   20px 0 0 -10px black,
   0 20px 0 -10px black,
   -20px 0 0 -10px black;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```